# Rake task is not called in production mode for ruby on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

From a controller:-

```
call_rake :parse_venue, :venue_list_id => venue_list.id


def call_rake(task, options = {})
   options[:rails_env] ||= Rails.env
   args = options.map { |n, v| "#{n.to_s.upcase}='#{v}'" }
   system "rake #{task} #{args.join(' ')} --trace 2>&1 >> #{Rails.root}/log/rake.log &"
end
```

In development mode this rake task is triggered.. But in case of production mode its not triggered.

PS:- Inspired from [rake in background, railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/127-rake-in-background). There is nothing in rake.log file in production mode

Comment: if the options are user generated in any way this is very dangerous. Imagine if I pass "k='s'; rm -rf /; 's".

Comment: @spike no issues.. as its not user generated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following system call:

```
system "#{args.join(' ')} rake #{task} --trace 2>&1 >> #{Rails.root}/log/rake.log &"
```

Answer (score 0):

Verify that "rake" is in the $PATH of the user running your web server / app server